# How to perform load test on rails based RESTful API?

Tags: rest, load-testing, rails-api

this might be wrong to ask here but Can anyone suggest me a tool to test a rails based RESTful API? I need to perform load or stress test on this API and also i should be able to write script i need. Basically what i need is a load test tool to test a rails based REST API with script.
P.S.: it should be freeware also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AgileLoad](http://www.agileload.com) to load test a RESTful API. It is free for scripting and small test, but have a license to be paid for more than 50 concurent users I think. The support team is quite proactive and can help you with advanced scripting features. They have also some tutorials and how to's available on their website.